# How do I replace elements in a list over a certain threshold with the previous element in that list?

Tags: python, arrays, list

I have a multiple numpy lists with thousands of data points each. There are spikes that are due to hardware issues that I wish to remove. My plan is to replace every spike with the previous element of the array to maintain consistency.

Comment: Are they 1D numpy arrays (important difference) or python lists? What have you tried so far? Is your specific problem with the start/end of the lists, or is it something else? If you describe your issue in more detail, explaining what you've done and how it's failed, then it will be more easy to help you. EDIT: if you have multiple 1D arrays, why not a single 2D array?

Comment: Please read [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and edit your question. Furthermore numpy does not have lists. Do you mean arrays? And spike/peak removal is a quite complicated task. Let alone **correctly** detecting peaks. Take a look at [`scipy.signal.find_peaks`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.find_peaks.html#scipy.signal.find_peaks) for one kind of peak detection.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to make the solution far too complicated. The easiest way is as follows;

```
for x in clockList:
    if x > 2000000000:
        clockList[count] = clockList[count - 1]
        count += 1
    else:
        count += 1
```